# Trying to test postfix so I can get nagios's email feature working

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

Hello I am trying to get postfix set up and working so I can get Nagios to email me whenever a server goes down, raid fails, etc. 
 The machine I have up is an Ubuntu server running in a virtual machine in hyper V. 
The machine is on the network and can ping the servers I want monitored, they are already configured to monitor, just not email me. I already have an exchange server running on actual hardware, as opposed to a VM, however it is my understanding that I still need postfix for Nagios to email me. I have Nagios running Apache2 and Postfix running. Their service status shows active (running). I get no errors when I restart their respective services. However whenever I telnet into postfix to send an example email to me. name@address.com  for example it gives me the error: 451 4.3.0 name@address.com: temporary lookup failure. I am rather new to postfix and Nagios, so please forgive any new mistakes.

I can post the contents of any logs or config files necessary, however I do not know in advance what you need to see. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Postfix is a bit of a bear. Trying SSMTP, a much lighter weight product that delivers emails but does not receive them.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a DNS entry problem. If you run 
 `dig address.com mx`  do you see a response that includes the mail server for address.com. If not, fix your DNS first then try again.